# cachegrind.out files still being stored at /tmp even after being purged,autoremoved

Tags: apt, package-management

I have uninstalled `kcachegrind` from my Ubuntu 14.04.I notice some files like `cachegrind.out.1606`,`cachegrind.out.2301` etc. being stored at `/tmp` directory.Each of this files have size of more than **10 MB**.When `/tmp` directory reaches certain size like **900 MB** it gives warning message to cleanup `/tmp` and makes it impossible for me to continue my work without restarting my machine.

I searched everywhere in my machine if any package named `kcachegrind` or its dependencies still exists but it shows unavailable.

Do I have to reinstall my Ubuntu again?

**Note:** I installed `kcachegrind` as per instruction in https://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/setting-up-kcachegrind-in-ubuntu/

Comment: `/tmp` directory isn't cleared out at boot or at shutdown?

Comment: On boot or shutdown ,it is clean up but if you are running more,size of `/tmp `getting increased